# DHCP and DNS on a custom internal vSwitch?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, hyper-v, dhcp

In Win 11 I've configured in Hyper-V a custom internal vSwitch with NAT as follows:

```
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName 'VM NAT switch' -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress '192.168.2.1' -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias 'vEthernet (VM NAT switch)'
New-NetNat -Name 'VM NAT' -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix '192.168.2.0/24'
```

It works but requires manual configuration of network connection (IP address, default gateway, DNS) in a guest operating system.

However, when the same VMs are connected to the Hyper-V default switch they're automatically (by DHCP I suppose) assigned with an IP address and configured to use the default switch as a default GW and a DNS server. Custom internal vSwitch doesn't provide DNS even when I set a guest OS to use the switch as a name server manually.

Looks like default switch in Hyper-V somehow provides VMs connected to it with DHCP and DNS. Is it possible to configure a custom internal vSwitch in the same way?